# Events do not fire for an OpenLayers Map object in a Vue serverless web application

Tags: javascript, vue.js, openlayers

I have a Vue serverless web application which has an OpenLayers map which is initialized in `mounted` and populated by `ImageWMS` layers which are updated by functions. I call `this.map.renderSync()` after every update parameters action and then try to execute another function when the rendering of all layers is complete (loaded and rendered all layers as the description of the `rendercomplete` event describes). To my surprise `this.map.on("rendercomplete",this.myFunction())`only fires once, when the map is initially rendered in `mounted`. What am I missing and how can I get `this.myFunction()` executed if and only if all the layers have been loaded and rendered after I update their parameters?

```
async mounted() {
    this.map = new Map({
        target: this.$refs['map'],
        layers: [
            this.osm,
            this.fwhotspots,
            this.surface25,
            this.surface10
        ],
        view: new View({
            center: fromLonLat([-97, 43]),
            zoom: 4
        })
    });
    this.map.on("rendercomplete", this.flagCallback());
},
methods: {
    setTimeSurface10: function () {
        if (this.currentTimeSurface10 === null) {
            this.currentTimeSurface10 = this.startTimeSurface10;
        } else if (this.currentTimeSurface10 >= this.endTimeSurface10) {
            this.currentTimeSurface10 = this.startTimeSurface10;
        } else {
            this.currentTimeSurface10 = new Date(
                this.currentTimeSurface10.setMinutes(this.currentTimeSurface10.getMinutes() + 60)
            );
        }
        this.surface10.getSource().updateParams({ TIME: this.currentTimeSurface10.toISOString().split(".")[0] + "Z" });
    },
    flagCallback: function () {
        console.log("RenderComplete Callback");
    },
    mapToCanvasList: function () {
        setTimeout(() => { 
            this.setTimeSurface10();
            this.map.renderSync();
            this.myCallback();
            console.log("First"); }, 1000);
        setTimeout(() => { 
            this.setTimeSurface10();
            this.map.renderSync();
            this.myCallback();
            console.log("2nd"); }, 2000);
        setTimeout(() => { 
            this.setTimeSurface10();
            this.map.renderSync();
            this.myCallback();
            console.log("3rd"); }, 3000);

        setTimeout(() => { 
            this.gif.on('finished', function(blob) {
            window.open(URL.createObjectURL(blob));});
            this.gif.render();
            }, 4000);
    },
    myCallback: function () {
        console.log("Callback Called");
        const mapCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        const divElement = document.querySelector(".map");
        mapCanvas.width = divElement.offsetWidth;//size[0];
        mapCanvas.height = divElement.offsetHeight;//size[1];
        const mapContext = mapCanvas.getContext('2d');
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(
            document.querySelectorAll('.ol-layer canvas'),
            function (canvas) {
                if (canvas.width > 0) {
                    const opacity = canvas.parentNode.style.opacity;
                    mapContext.globalAlpha = opacity === '' ? 1 : Number(opacity);
                    const transform = canvas.style.transform;
                    const matrix = transform
                                            .match(/^matrix\(([^\(]*)\)$/)[1] //eslint-disable-line
                                            .split(',')
                                            .map(Number);
                    CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.setTransform.apply(mapContext,matrix);
                    mapContext.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);
                }
            }
        );
        this.gif.addFrame(mapCanvas, {copy:true, delay: 200});
        console.log("Callback End");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.map.on` has 2 arguments, the name of the event as string (`"rendercomplete"`), and a callback function. Your callback function is `this.flagCallback`, without the `()`. You can see the console logging once, because the function is invoked once when the listener is created.

Comment: Thank Mr. Rob. Can you explain to me the difference between `this.flagCallback` and `this.flagCallback()` please? Also can you please help me with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69921722/vue-sequential-execution)? I am trying to add the canvas to a GIF object only once the layers have rendred and do this after updating the time params of the layers.

Comment: when calling (or invoking) a function, the return value is what the function returns. In JS this can be anything, even another function, in your case the flagCallback does not return anything, so basically your faulty listener looked like this: `this.map.on('rendercomplete', undefined)`, now it looks like this: `this.map.on('rendercomplete', someFunction)`

Comment: The listener is trying to call that second argument every time the 'rendercomplete'-Event happened, but you didnt see anything because the listener was trying to call `undefined` over and over again